# How to launch nav2 without prior map?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to setup a nav2 simulation for my robot.
The bringup_launch.py expects a yaml map as input.
I don't want to provide a prior map, but if I don't provide it the robot won't move when I send a goal.
I expected that nav2 would use the global and local maps...

Is it possible to use Nav2 without a prior map ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401976/how-to-launch-nav2-without-prior-map-?/) by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2022-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is, e.g. during SLAM:

https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_slam.html#launch-navigation2

> ##1- Launch Navigation2
>
> Launch Navigation without nav2_amcl
> and nav2_map_server. It is assumed
> that the SLAM node(s) will publish to
> `/map` topic and provide the `map->odom`
> transform.
>
> ```
> ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py
> ```
>
> ##2- Launch SLAM
>
> Bring up your choice of SLAM
> implementation. Make sure it provides
> the map->odom transform and /map
> topic. Run Rviz and add the topics you
> want to visualize such as /map, /tf,
> /laserscan etc. For this tutorial, we
> will use SLAM Toolbox.
>
> ```
> ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py
> ```
>
> ##3- Working with SLAM
>
> Move your robot by requesting a goal
> through RViz or the ROS 2 CLI (...)

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2022-06-06**:
Thanks for your answer @ljaniec, but I just want to make a quick test without setting up slam.
Is it possible to use the local map instead ?

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2022-06-06**:
It is working. I set the map_topic (which defaults to /map) to "/global_costmap/costmap".
Thanks!

**Comment by [MrOCW](https://answers.ros.org/users/95995/mrocw/) on 2022-06-10**:
Hi @Acwok, I am attempting navigation without a map. Is that what you are trying to achieve? May I know what are your nav2 parameters?

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2022-06-10**:
Hi @MrOCW, I'm doing navigation without a prior map, but I still have the global_costmap and local_costmap enabled otherwise the robot cannot know where are the obstacles.
I plan to do SLAM in the future but I was doing this just to try things.
Here is my param file http://pastebin.fr/107286, hope it helps

**Comment by [Ãustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/78793/%C3%A3ustin/) on 2022-08-15**:
Hi @Acwok, would you be able to send that Pastebin again? It seems it has gone dead. I'm also trying to get Nav2 working without a prior map, or any SLAM